# Internet Explorer 9 does not remove load mask on Ext.getBody using Extjs 4.2.2

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs4, loadmask

I am using Extjs 4.2.2, on site load I am using Ext.getBody.mask('some msg') and on unload I use Ext.getBody.unmask();

I see its working nicely on all the browsers except Internet Explorer 9. Here it doesn't remove the loading mask. But when I open Developer Tool for IE9, using F12 and refresh the page, it does fine as other browsers.

Comment: I could solve this issue: I used console.log in my code, which is not read by Internet explorer 9 unless its developer tool is opened. I removed it and things are working fine again..

Hope this information is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue: I used console.log in my code, which is not read by Internet explorer 9 unless its developer tool is opened. I removed it and things are working fine again.. Hope this information is helpful to someone.